# wordpress tinymce add blocks of html code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce

I know you can add style formats to wordpress through the functions.php file which is great for buttons e.g:

```
<button class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

But does anyone know a solution if you wanted to add entire sections of code from a dropdown or a similar method other than defining it in  a template page? So, for example, you could add html code below by selecting from a dropdown or clicking a button from the WYSIWYG TinyMCE editor:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center logo">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="google.com">
  <img class="responsive" src="#" />
  </a>
</div>
```

So there are multiple tags and classes.

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Content Blocks plugin or implement shortcodes?

Comment: Ahh...perfect - global content blocks worked a treat! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wordpress Plugin called Content Blocks that lets you do this sort of thing.